# How to close mysqli connection on AWS instance?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I am aware that [similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625963/how-to-close-a-datasource-mysql-connection) were given before, but I feel that my issue is somehow context-specific. My apologies if it turns out to be an exact duplicate, I am very open to suggestions on how to make the post clearer.

I am having a hard time replicating the issue, so I have to "qualitatively" describe the issue. 
What I have, is a html form that has to be submitted to a mysql db hosted on AWS. The issue is that the .php that contains the query to write on the db doesn't always work. I know it's a vague depiction of the issue, but what happens is that it works when I test it from the devices I have available, but in my real case scenario (a survey on Mturk) it misses most of the connections.

I wonder if it might be a memory issue, because I keep seeing under "Current Activity" that there are connections opened, even though I specified in my php `mysqli_close($conn);`

[image]

However, the survey on MTurk has been so far published in 1 batch of 9 people at a time, so even assuming the connection aren't being closed...is it a number that might generate issue if all the sql does is posting a form?

I have been suggested to look at `show processlist` while running the query, and this is the output after submitting the form 3-4 times in a row:
[image]

Comment: Connections are closed automatically when the script is finished. If it's not working, troubleshoot the code and query by using the error functions instead of trying to guess. You can also check the mysql processlist to see if there are any long running queries.

Comment: @aynber Here is the thing, the code works from my device...I am not sure how to use the error functions then. Which type of error should I look for?

Comment: Check for mysqli_error() along the way of your code, and log into the mysql database and watch `show processlist` while the code is running.

Comment: @aynber OP updated. Not sure if that helps. What else would you suggest?